# Browserify: IE8 Compatibility

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, browserify

I've seen it mentioned in a few places that Browserify isn't compatible with IE8 and below ([here](http://www.linkedin.com/groups/RequireJS-vs-Browserify-121615.S.5815875689840144385), [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/socketstream/GiTQmve6Qi4/eEwbP7YEZnMJ), and alluded to [here](https://gist.github.com/desandro/4686136#comment-764677)).

I don't see anything official about this in the docs. It looks like it may be the use of [Function.prototype.call()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) but I can't tell for sure.

Does anyone know for sure:

- how far back IE is supported
- what code (if any) is incompatible with IE8
- any recommended workarounds for IE8 specifically

Answer (score 7):

I use Browserify for my library http://github.com/pllee/luc to build all of the browser code.  My tests pass on IE6 and I am using ES5 shim but I don't think that would make Browserify work (chicken and egg situation).  Those links you show are quite old and I know Browserify has changed its implementation since then.

You can see on their official [page](http://browserify.org/) that they do support IE7 and greater.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for responding. I did see that chart on the homepage, but I think it's referring to how to tell a **module's** browser compatibility as opposed to Browserify's. The sentence before says "Many modules known to work with browserify will have a testling-ci badge..." Glad to hear you haven't run into any issues; I'm writing a simple bundle to test out and will post my results here to confirm.

Comment: @cantera I think that sentence before is kind of a promotion for the testling badge, it was created by the same person as Browserify.  I think most libraries/tools that have badges should run/support the passing versions.  I'll be interested to see if for some reason your simple test doesn't pass.